# Insert trigger if record exists - Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have tables:

**DEPARTMETS** with dep_id(number), dep_name(varchar), `manager_id`(number) fields.

**EMPLOYEES** with employee_id(number), name(varchar), salary(number), `manager_id`(number)

I want to create a trigger which it is responsible for check if exists `manager_id` into table **DEPARTMENTS** when data is inserted or updated to table **EMPLOYEES**

Trigger could be something like:

```
create or update trigger manager_exists
before insert or update on employees 
for each row
begin
  if exists **new id** into Departments then
    INSERT DATA IN EMPLOYEES
  else
    "Error: MANAGER_ID doesnt exists in Departments"
  end if;
end manager_exists;
```

But I can't figure out how to create this trigger.
Note:I need it to be a trigger please. HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood the question:

```
create or replace trigger manager_exists
  before insert or update on employees
  for each row
declare
  l_mgr number;
begin
  select 1
    into l_mgr
    from dual
    where exists (select null 
                  from departments d
                  where d.manager_id = :new.manager_id
                 );
exception
  when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'That manager does not exist in DEPARTMENTS');
end manager_exists;
```

In other words:

- check whether `MANAGER_ID` you're trying to insert into `EMPLOYEES` table exists in `DEPARTMENTS` table

  - though, that doesn't make much sense to me; I'd say that you should check it vice versa - check whether `MANAGER_ID` you're trying to insert into `DEPARTMENTS` exists in `EMPLOYEES` table ... but that's not what you wrote (or I misunderstood what you said)
- if so, fine, don't do anything (in a trigger); `insert` or `update` statement which caused the trigger to fire will do the job
- if not, raise an error

Comment: Thank you. What happens is that in the "EMPLOYEES" table a manager_id can be in several employees and when a new employee is registered it must be known if the manager_id that is added exists in the "DEPARTMENTS" table.

But I think it's fine how you did it above

Comment: You're welcome. If that's so, then OK, I'm glad if it helped.